# Token FCM (google) associar ao Usuario, em que momento?

Tags: google, firebase

Um app que tem Cadastro e Login de Usuarios, consequentemente um ID pra cada Usuario.

Em que momento é gerado o Token FCM ?

Eu implementando dentro de: onTokenRefresh() , o Token pode ser gerado antes de eu ter um Usuario com ID para eu associar...

Pergunto isso, porque, se for gerado antes de o Usuario se cadastrar, como que eu associo o Token ao Usuario ?

Answer (score 1):

Documentação oficial traduzida : [DOCUMENTAÇÃO](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)

Na primeira inicialização do aplicativo, o FCM SDK gera um token de registro da instância do aplicativo cliente. Para direcionar o aplicativo a dispositivos únicos ou criar grupos de dispositivos, será necessário acessar este token.

Obs.: A cada autenticação, um novo token é gerado para o usuário. Por este motivo eu gravo o token na SharedPreferences pois só é possível ter acesso a esse token durante a autenticação. Como sugestão, segue abaixo como fiz para gravar o token atual na SharedPreferences:

Adicione o serviço no **manifesto**:

```
    <service
        android:name=".Messaging.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Classe **.Messaging.FirebaseIDService** com a gravação do token na **SharedPreferences**:

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SP.edit();
        editor.putString("CfgTokenFCM", token);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Pronto. Agora podes fazer a leitura do token em qualquer classe e quando bem entender com :

```
        // Read CfgTokenFCM
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        cfgTokenFCM = SP.getString("CfgTokenFCM", "");
```

Eu particularmente ainda gravo no **firebase realtime database** em um nó específico para usuários, com **UserID**, **UserName**, **UserEmail**, **PhotoURL** e etc.