# Token de registro não registrado - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho um projeto no firebase e estou tentando implementar as notificações de push, segui a documentação mas ao fazer testes, de envio direto no firebase, ele falha e aparece o erro, "Token de Registro não registrado".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".util.appFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".util.appFirebaseRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="true"> <!-- tentei com e sem esta tag-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Classes:

```
public class appFirebaseRegistrationIntentService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("Token da App", token);
    }
}

public class appFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
     //todo
}
```

Não consigo encontrar meu erro. Pego o token que está na variável `token` , coloco na mensagem escolhendo o dispositivo único(no console do firebase), mas ainda sim, tenho o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada vez que você faz o login, é gerado um novo token.
Estas usando o ultimo token gerado para enviar a mensagem ?

Meu palpite é que possas estar usando um token expirado para enviar a mensagem push.

Eu costumo gravar o ultimo token nas shared preferences e no onCreate na parte de autenticação do firebase auth, gravo no realtime database em um nó específico com dados do usuário.(se quiser publico o trecho destes codigos para armazenamento do ultimo token gerado).

[Token FCM (google) associar ao Usuario, em que momento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153835/token-fcm-google-associar-ao-usuario-em-que-momento/211174#211174)

- ====== A T U A L I Z A Ç Ã O =======

Trechos de códigos que uso:

Manifesto:

```
    <service android:name=".Messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".Messaging.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

.Messaging.FirebaseIDService:

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SP.edit();
        editor.putString("CfgTokenFCM", token);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

.Messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

.Models.User:

```
// [START blog_user_class]
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String photo;
    public String token;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email, String photo, String token) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.token = token;
    }

    // [START user_to_map]
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {

        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

        result.put("username", username);
        result.put("email", email);
        result.put("photo", photo);
        result.put("token", token);

        return result;
    }
    // [END posto_to_map]

}
// [END blog_user_class]
```

MainActivity (onCreate):

```
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
        mPhotoUrl = "";
        mUserName = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        mUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
        mUserEmail = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
        if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }

        // Read CfgTokenFCM
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        cfgTokenFCM = SP.getString("CfgTokenFCM", "");

        // Write user data in SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SP.edit();
        editor.putString("CfgUserID", mUserID);
        editor.apply();

        // Write user data in firebase
        User user = new User( mUserName , mUserEmail, mPhotoUrl, cfgTokenFCM);
        Map<String, Object> userValues = user.toMap();
        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put("/users/" + mUserID, userValues);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(childUpdates);
    }
```

Comment: Eu, desinstalo por exemplo o app e debugo colocando o break ali, então pego o token e tento enviar a mensagem. Se este não for o que é gerado para o registro, gostaria de um trecho de código sim, mas este é o código da documentação do firebase.

Comment: Não testei em **debug mode**, mas no teste que acabei de realizar em um aplicativo publicado e em outro em versão beta, utilizando os tokens gravados no **firebase realtime database** dentro do nó com as informações de usuário, funcionou perfeitamente e recebi a notificação FCM instantaneamente. O código que postei como exemplo mantém o token sempre atualizado no banco de dados de usuários do firebase.

Comment: O código que vc utiliza é o mesmo, o problema realmente está no debug, com o app em release ele funciona. Agradeço ajuda!! Vou verificar o motivo de em debug não funcionar.